# block animations: set UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

Sorry, this is very basic, but I can't set the AnimationOption from the default (EaseIn) to CurveLinear. This is what I tried based on what I read in other threads:

```
    -(void)animationShadow;
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
...
```

If I take out the the options bit, everything works fine. If not, it crashes. I'm sure I haven't called the right commands.

Here is the entire block animation:

```
   -(void)animationShadow;
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{

        //UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear

        // animation 1
        [pageShadowView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale (3, 1)];
        [pageShadowView setFrame:CGRectMake(0-350, 0, CGRectGetWidth(pageShadowView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(pageShadowView.frame))];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"pageCurlRightToLeftFinished" context:nil]; // Begin animation
        //[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        [pageShadowView setFrame:CGRectMake(0-280, 0, CGRectGetWidth(pageShadowView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(pageShadowView.frame))];
        [UIView commitAnimations];



    } completion:^(BOOL finished){ ...
```

**EDIT:**

OK, I now updated this, but I still crashes if I do the second the animation. I get the warning: UIView may not respond to +animateWithDuration ...:

-(void)animationShadow;
{

```
[pageShadowView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale (3, 1)];
[pageShadowView setFrame:CGRectMake(0-350, 0, CGRectGetWidth(pageShadowView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(pageShadowView.frame))];


[UIView animateWithDuration:kPageCurlSpeed/4
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
            [pageShadowView setFrame:CGRectMake(0-280, 0, CGRectGetWidth(pageShadowView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(pageShadowView.frame))];
                            }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                     [UIView animateWithDuration:kPageCurlSpeed
                                           delay:0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                      animations:^{
                                          // animation 2

                                          [pageShadowView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale (0.1, 1)];
                                          [pageShadowView setFrame:CGRectMake((340-pageShadowView.frame.size.width), 0, CGRectGetWidth(pageShadowView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(pageShadowView.frame))];

                                      }
                      ]; // this is where I get the warning!!



                     }];

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** animation initialization code should be placed outside of the animation block. The block specifies the final state the views should reach at the end of animation.

```
[pageShadowView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3, 1)];
[pageShadowView setFrame:CGRectMake(-350, ...)];

[UIView animateWithDuration:4 delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
                 animations:^{
                              [pageShadowView setFrame:CGRectMake(-280, ...)];
                            }
                 completion:NULL];
```

---

If you want to run 2 animations sequentially, the 2nd one should be put in the `completion` block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4 delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{ /* animation 1 */ }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                               /* animation 2 */
                            }];
```

Comment: @KeenyTM: Thanks for your response. Well, actually, that's what I am trying to do. I just presented the first animation here. Will I not need to put the [pageShadowView setTransform... etc. until [UIView commitAnimations]; into the place which you've marked as /* animation 1 */? I guess I don't get the concept of the block animation yet. Are you saying that I have two animations in the code presented above? I just tried to defined the starting point of my animation (x= -350) and the end point (x = -280), so I thought this was just one animation, i.e. from x=-350 to x=-280. Thanks for yourhelp!

Comment: @KennyTm: Thanks so much for your help. I think I get the concept now, but I'm still not sure about the second animation. I updated my code -- please see above -- and it still crashes. I'm sure I am not initiating the second animation the way I should.

Comment: @n.ever: You are missing the `delay:0`.

Comment: @KennyTm: I still get the UIView may not respond to +animateWithDuration ...: warning at the ]; three lines from the bottom (I marked it above). What am I missing? Sorry to be such a pain. `[UIView animateWithDuration:kPageCurlSpeed delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{ // ... } ];` should do the job, shouldn't it?

Comment: @KennyTm: To be more precise, this is what the debugger tells me: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x858538'

Comment: @n.ever: All 5 parameters (duration, delay, options, animations, completion) are required. You cannot omit or reorder any of them even if it is NULL or 0. This applies to all Objective-C methods in general.

Comment: I see, but if I comment out delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear it works perfectly... anyways, I'll give this a try. So I guess I need the completion once more, but simply tell the programme to do no animation at all? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks!! It works perfectly now. Thank you so much for your patience in this, I really really appreciate your help.

Comment: @n.ever: That's because there is also a method that accepts only the duration and animations. You can check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108.

Answer (score 5):

If you find that your selected curve is being ignored, check that you are using the right set of switches.

There is one called **UIViewAnimationCurveLinear** (for older methods) and **UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear** (for block methods) and its easy to mix them up. there are corresponding equivalent pairs for ease in, ease out etc.

This caught me out so I thought I'd make sure the information was easily visible for others.